# 1-5v throttle signal to 0-5v

Tags: voltage

I’m trying to adapt a new speed controller onto my motor. It uses 0-5v for the throttle input. The throttle I have now uses a hall sensor that can only do 1-5v so the motor will continue to roll even when the throttle is not being pressed. What is a way that I could get the voltage down to 0v but still have the voltage be 5v at max.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work for you:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjdGQv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Using a 7805 as a voltage *reference*... That's an unusual sight!

Comment: @Hearth It's actually a bandgap reference and not too terrible if lightly loaded.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't think it wouldn't work, it's just an unusual sight!

Comment: What's the purpose of the 1M shunt?

Comment: @Reinderien on the LM358, bias current flows out of the input, so without the resistor a broken connection to the input would result in full throttle.

Answer (score 0):

This is a standard application for an op amp configured for gain and offset, as described by Texas Instruments [in application report SLOA097](http://web.archive.org/web/20210301151822/https://www.ti.com/lit/an/sloa097/sloa097.pdf).

We're looking to map [1,5] V to [0,5] V; we hence need a gain of 1.25 and an offset of -1.25 V at the output. Select a rail-to-rail op amp to reach the entire range using a 0-5 V supply; you'll also need a reference voltage to establish the offset.

The topology will look as follows (reproduced from the above link):

[image]

The values of the resistors can be established using the equations linked in that application report (or derived from the circuit topology).

Comment: SparkFun (PID 09816 OpAmp Breakout - LMV358 https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01N5OKOOW/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_api_glt_fabc_MKXCAE7FMP4VDN2D96NF

Would this work for my application?

Comment: No. It's already wired to a different topology: "Set up as a 2-stage amplifier with a total gain of 100 (gain of 10 for each stage)", whereas both my answer and [the other answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/563994/9612) require particular wiring around the op amp that doesn't match the setup on that board.

Comment: Ok, I’m very confused at the moment but I’ll read up on it and try to figure it out.